# (iOS) crash when view controller property is set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've problems passing data to a new view controller.

I've two VC. In the "FirstVC" there is a table view with dynamic prototypes cells. The generic cell contains a label and a button and it's assigned to its own class "GenericCell". I want to pass to the SecondVC the text of the cell label when I press the button, but the app crashes with errors:

> Unknown class _TtC13testTableView37SecondVC in Interface Builder file.
>
> UIViewController setMyString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa05e418110
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setMyString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc8add05710

I tried:

1. To use the segue (with prepareForSegue method) outside the getText method

   1a. Pushing the VC from the outside of the getText method
2. Implementing and calling set/get method of myString
3. Adding attributes to myString property

but the app crashes the same.

**GenericCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol MyCellDelegate
-(void)getText:(NSString *)text;
@end

@interface GenericCell: UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * label;
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <MyCellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**GenericCell.m**

```
#import "GenericCell.h"
@interface GenericCell()
@end

@implementation GenericCell

- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate getText:self.label.text];
    }
}
@end
```

**FirstVC.m**

```
#import "FirstVC.h"
#import "GenericCell.h"
#import "SecondVC.h"

@interface FirstVC() <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, MyCellDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property NSString * idToPass;
@end

@implementation FirstVC


NSMutableArray<NSString *> *array;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0x22", @"0x11", @"0x24", nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.rowHeight=100;
}

-(void)getText:(NSString *)text {
   self.idToPass = text;

   SecondVC * secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
   secondVC.myString = self.idToPass;
   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return array.count;
}

- (GenericCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    GenericCell * cell = [[self tableView]dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GenericCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.label.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

**SecondVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SecondVC : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property NSString * myString;
@end
```

**SecondVC.m**

```
#import "SecondVC.h"

@interface SecondVC ()
@end

@implementation SecondVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.label.text = self.myString;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

The "idToPass" is set correctly with delegation.

Comment: "'NSInvalidArgumentException': unrecognized selector sent to instance" Show the whole error message, it should give info on the method called (could be a getter or a setter), and the class that is "mismatched".

Comment: Check that your SecondVC inside your storyboard really is a `SecondVC` object as set in the Class field of the Identity inspector.  The error message says it's a plain `UIViewController`.

Comment: @PhillipMills  Storyboard ID?

Comment: There's nothing to suggest that your ID is wrong.  I'm more suspicious that you haven't set the custom class name.

Comment: Now that I look at *both* errors, this seems strange: "Unknown class _TtC13testTableView37SecondVC in Interface Builder file."  Do you have it set as part of a module perhaps?

Comment: @PhillipMills I writed the title in the attributes inspector and now the first error is fixed.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of interface builder of SecondVC? To be specific Identity inspector with SecondVC selected?

Comment: Have you embedded first view controller in navigation controller?

Comment: Can you please check if secondVC is nil?

secondVC.myString = self.idToPass; this line.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you have paste here, You can check this repo, if you able to find you find something, https://github.com/mashuvo/CodeTest

Comment: What was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me: in the buttonPressed method update the if statement like this

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getText:)]){
        [self.delegate getText:self.label.text];
}
```

Another option to give SecondVC the data is using

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    SecondVC * vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"yourSegue"]) {
        vc.myString = self.idToPass;
    }
}
```

A tip I suggest is to check (with a simple if statement) if your object in SecondVC is nil or !nil

I hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

In getText method you assign text to myProperty instead myString...

It should be:

```
secondVC.myString = self.idToPass;
```

Comment: I'm so sorry if I copied badly here. I correct immediately